# How to check a specific item in a list in c#

Tags: c#, arraylist

Currently, I am working on a simulator for a network consists of 200 sensor nodes. In my code, I need each node to send hello packet to its neighbors. In previous step, I wrote a code to broadcast hello message from specific nodes to their neighbors which they are sensor nodes. Now, I need these sensor nodes to re-forward the hello packet in its queue to its neighbors. I need to check the queue of the sensor node if it is already has a hello packet in order to re-forward it to the neighbors of this sensor node . . .

As example, I created the hello like this :

```
 Packet hello = new Packet(CNs[i].cnID, i, i, 0, CNs[i].cnDepth, DateTime.Now, "Hello, I am a Courier node near of you");
```

The packet is declared like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace AUV_Topology
{
    class Packet    
    {    
        public int senderID;
        public int nextID;
        public int recieverID;
        public int packetSequenceNum;
        public int depth;
        public DateTime sendingTime;
        public String data;

        public Packet(int sID, int nID, int rID, int pSecNum, int depth,DateTime sTime, String data)    
        {    
            this.senderID = sID;
            this.nextID = nID;
            this.recieverID = rID;
            this.packetSequenceNum = pSecNum;
            this.depth = depth;
            this.sendingTime = sTime;
            this.data = data;   
        }    
    }
}
```

To ensure that the sensor node queue has a hello packet received from another node, I use "foreach" and check if each packet inside the list contains "Hello, I am a Courier node near of you" …

Unfortunately, I tried to use

```
SNs[i]queue.contains("Hello, I am a Courier node near of you");
```

where `SN[i]` is an array of sensor nodes and the queue is an attribute declared as follows:

```
public List<Packet> queue = new List<Packet>();
```

But I get a syntax error:

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'AUV_Topology.Packet'   AUVs_TOPOLOGY

How can I do this?

Is this a possible solution:

```
 for(int j=0; j < NodeNum; j++)
 {   
   if (SNsNighbors[i, j] == 1)
      {
         String temp = SNs[i].queue.ToString();
         if (temp.Contains("Hello"))
         {
         }    
      }    
  }
```

Comment: If class is `public`, it compiles.

Comment: `SNs[i]queue.Contains(...)` - Capital letter `C` in `Contains`?

Comment: Please put more code, because you say that the queue is an attribute but what is an attribute? I don't understand attribute in context of an array.

Comment: "I got an error" - please say what the exact type and error message text was - "Guess what error this code throws" is a good game, but it takes quite a while to play :)

Comment: @CaiusJard : I've added the error ….

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `queue` is a list of Packet and you want to know if any of those Packets have a `data` that is a hello message, make sure you've imported LINQ and do this:

```
SNs[i].queue.Any(pkt => pkt.data == "Hello, I am a Courier node near of you");
```

This returns a bool true if any packets have that data. If you want to retrieve the first packet with this data, swap Any for First. If multiple packets have it and you want all of them swap it for Where

ps; in C# we name public members with a initial capital letter, Data, Queue and so on, and we prefer public properties rather than public variables. Also if it's more appropriate to use a FIFO queue to model your Queue, the System.Collections.Generic namespace has one of those alongside List

Comment: please how to know the index in the queue  of this pkt ??

Comment: List has a FindIndex method that takes a predicate in order to calculate whether a particular element should be "found" - substitute Any for FindIndex